# factory girl fixture data is undefined trying to get spec go green cant sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a sign_in_spec.rb in spec/features

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'user signs in' do
  before(:all) do 
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
  end

  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  @javascript
  scenario 'with valid credentials' do
    visit('/users/sign_in')
    fill_in('Email', :with => user.email)
    fill_in('Password', :with => user.password)
    click_button('Sign in')
    page.should have_content 'Signed in successfully'
  end

  @javascript
  scenario 'with invalid password' do
    visit('/users/sign_in')
    fill_in('Email', :with => user.email)
    fill_in('Password', :with => 'incorrect')
    click_button('Sign in')
    page.should have_content 'Invalid email or password'
  end
end
```

I am having trouble with the first scenario. Here is my factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do 
    email 'judy.ngai1228@gmail.com'
    password 'crackers'
  end 
end
```

according to the factorygirl doc the create method should returned a saved instance. I even created an user with the factory girl defined email/password in rails c test environment and the development environment.

When I run the test, I keep on getting

```
invalid password/username
```

it just won't be posted/can't sign in. I am using database cleaner to clean out the test environment..... but the factory girl create method should do the trick.

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
#require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'database_cleaner'


include Warden::Test::Helpers 
Warden.test_mode!

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  #use database cleaner instead
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do 
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end 

  config.before :each do  
    DatabaseCleaner.start 
  end 

  config.after :each do 
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end 
end
```

updated made the password longer

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do 
    email 'judy.ngai1228@gmail.com'
    password 'crackers123456'
  end 
end
```

still not working.

Comment: is `crackers` a valid password for your password validation rules?

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares oh that is right, it may need to be longer. I will give it a try. No it didn't work, I went into the dev/test db to change it too. Modifying factory girl should be enough.